# Controlling scatterhist bar colors

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, histogram, scatter-plot

I was trying to make the bars in my `scatterhist` plot be of the same color as the markers:

```
x = randn(1,20);
y = randn(1,20);
myColour = [1 0 0]; % red
scatterhist(x, y, 'Color', myColour);
mygca = get(gca,'children');
set(mygca,'markerfacecolor', myColour);
```

However, the bars are of a slightly different color, namely a reddish hue, [249 96 96]:
[image]

The Scatterhist [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/scatterhist.html) seems to suggest bar colors just follow marker color, which in this case does not happen.

How can I control color of the `scatterhist` bars, on MATLAB R2016a?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the bars have an **alpha** (transparency) setting.

To fix this, make sure the `'FaceAlpha'` setting is set to 1. For example:

```
x = randn(1,20);
y = randn(1,20);
myColour = [1 0 0];
hSh = scatterhist(x, y, 'Color', myColour);
hSh(1).Children.MarkerFaceColor = myColour;
hSh(2).Children.FaceAlpha = 1;
hSh(3).Children.FaceAlpha = 1;
```

Which yields:

[image: Proper colors]

Comment: how do you set the transparency on the markers too??

Comment: @OliverAmundsen as explained in [this blog post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient), `hMarkers = hSh(1).Children.MarkerHandle; hMarkers.FaceColorType = 'truecoloralpha'; hMarkers.FaceColorData = uint8(255*[1;0;0;0.3]);`. It's best if you asked a separate question, and linked to this post for context.

Comment: I created a question, please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628007/controlling-scatterhist-marker-transparency