# Controlling scatterhist Marker Transparency

Tags: matlab, transparency, scatter-plot, contour, histogram2d

I need to control the transparency of the markers in the figure produced with the `scatterhist` command in MATLAB.

[image: fig1]

The following post is helpful in handling the color of the histograms: [Controlling scatterhist bar colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466320/controlling-scatterhist-bar-colors/50466995#comment103559203_50466995).

1. How can the transparency of the markers be modified?
2. How can I add a contour plot on top of the markers?

Comment: Could you please clarify what information the contour is supposed to contain? Point density?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: 
In MATLAB R2019a,
[`scatterhist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/scatterhist.html) can do contours but it is difficult (yet [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466320/controlling-scatterhist-bar-colors/50466995#comment103562645_50466995)) to add marker transparency, and
[`scatterhistogram()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatterhistogram.html) can easily do transparency but contours are difficult.

See the third option below using [`alpha()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alpha.html), [`scatter()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html), and [`histogram()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) which builds this from scratch.

---

```
% MATLAB R2019a
n = 250;                % Number of Points
X = exprnd(3,n,1);
Y = gamrnd(9,1/3,n,1);
```

**Using** [**`scatterhistogram()`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatterhistogram.html)**:**

You can adjust the marker transparency with the `MarkerAlpha` Property.

[image: Plot using scatterhistogram with marker transparency but no contours.]

```
T = table(X,Y);
figure
s = scatterhistogram(T,'X','Y',...
    'HistogramDisplayStyle','smooth',...
    'LineStyle','-')
s.MarkerAlpha = 0.5;                    %  adjust transparency
```

The documentation demonstrates variations of this technique.

Notice that [`scatterhistogram()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatterhistogram.html) cannot be used with `hold on` either before or after, which prevents using [this solution from MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/225934-using-matlab-to-plot-density-contour-for-scatter-plot).

```
% This will give an error in R2019a
figure
s = scatterhistogram(T,'X','Y','HistogramDisplayStyle','smooth','LineStyle','-')
hold on
[m,c] = hist3([X', Y']);            % [m,c] = hist3([X(:), Y(:)]);
contour(c{1},c{2},m)
```

**Using** [**`scatterhist()`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/scatterhist.html)**:**

If you name `s = scatterhist(X,Y)`, then `s(1)` is the scatter plot, `s(2)` & `s(3)` are the histograms. This allows you to change properties. Notice that `s(1).Children.MarkerFaceColor = 'b'` works fine but there is no `MarkerAlpha` or `MarkerFaceAlpha` property (you'll get an error telling you so).

But, **contours are possible**. I think transparency is possible to based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466320/controlling-scatterhist-bar-colors/50466995#comment103562645_50466995) from @[Dev-iL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3372061/dev-il), but I haven't figured it out yet.

[image: Plot using scatterhist with contours but no marker transparency.]

```
figure
s = scatterhist(X,Y,'Direction','out')
s(1).Children.Marker = '.'
hold on
[m,c] = hist3([X(:), Y(:)]);
ch = contour(c{1},c{2},m)
```

**Build it from scratch:**
Obviously the entire thing can be manually constructed from scratch (but that's not appealing).

Using the [`alpha()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alpha.html) command gets it done.

[image: Scatterplot with histograms, transparency, and contours.]

```
figure1 = figure;

% Create axes
axes1 = axes('Tag','scatter','Parent',figure1,...
    'Position',[0.35 0.35 0.55 0.55]);
hold(axes1,'on');

% Create plot
s = scatter(X,Y,'Parent',axes1,'MarkerFaceColor','r','Marker','o');

ylabel('Y');
xlabel('X');
box(axes1,'on');
% Create axes
axes2 = axes('Tag','yhist','Parent',figure1,...
    'Position',[0.0325806451612903 0.35 0.217016129032258 0.55]);
axis off
hold(axes2,'on');

% Create histogram
hx = histogram(X,'Parent',axes2,'FaceAlpha',1,'FaceColor','r',...
    'Normalization','pdf',...
    'BinMethod','auto');
view(axes2,[270 90]);
box(axes2,'on');

% Create axes
axes3 = axes('Tag','xhist','Parent',figure1,...
    'Position',[0.35 0.0493865030674847 0.55 0.186679572132827]);
axis off
hold(axes3,'on');

% Create histogram
hy = histogram(Y,'Parent',axes3,'FaceAlpha',1,'FaceColor','r',...
    'Normalization','pdf',...
    'BinMethod','auto');
box(axes3,'on');
axis(axes3,'ij');

[m,c] = hist3([X(:), Y(:)]);
contour(axes1,c{1},c{2},m)

alphaVal = 0.3;
alpha(s,0.5)            % Set Transparency
alpha(hx,0.5)
alpha(hy,0.5)
```

---

**References:**
1. [Access Property Values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/access-and-modify-property-values.html) in MATLAB
2. [Plot markers transparency and color gradient](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient)

Answer (score 0):

For Matlab versions prior to 2018, **scatterhistogram** isn't available. And so, I found an alternative easy way to accomplish that markers have transparency:

```
figure
scatterhist(X,Y,'Kernel','on'); hold on
hdl = get(gca,'children');
set(hdl,'MarkerEdgeColor','none')
scatter(hdl.XData,hdl.YData,50,'MarkerFaceColor','r',...
'MarkerEdgeColor','none','MarkerFaceAlpha',0.2)
```

This works nicely.

[image]